# How do I loop through checked results on a coldfusion page and pass checked records to another page

Tags: checkbox, coldfusion, cfloop

How can I loop through results on a coldfusion page and grab the ids of the records that are checked and send just a list of ids to another page to be queried? The ids of the records are in the field next to the checkbox. Here is an example:

```
check  tag_num    serial_#  po_number  descrip
 []    FT0077769   test    12345       test   
 []    FT0077776   test    12345       test 
 []    FT0077789   test    12345       test
```

If I check the first two records I want to send over the tag_num to another page to be queried and display only those two records.

I know I need to use a cfloop list and that I need to have a ',' list, but I also need to put each tag in ' ' because that list will go to a query on the processing page. 
I am just not sure where this goes in the first page. Inside the form?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to see which items a user has checked? You could use jQuery to find checked rows.  Or you can set this up as a form and set the id of the checkboxes to their corresponding tag_num.

Comment: RE: *need to put each tag in ' ' because that list will go to a query* No you don't. Just use [`cfqueryparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) and no quotes needed. More importantly, it protects queries from sql injection. Also, take at look the `list` attribute. I suspect you could use that with a `WHERE Col IN (...)` clause instead of looping.

Comment: You did not provide enough information.  Where does the "checking" of a record occur?

Answer (score 4):

If you name all of your check boxes the same name, each with a different ID and value, you'll automatically get a list on the action page.

The form will look like this:
`<cfloop query="myQuery">
   <input type="checkbox" name="tag" id="tag_#myQuery.tag_num#" value="#myQuery.tag_num#" />
</cfloop>`

Now, when you check any of these check boxes and submit the form (using `action="post"`), the action page will be able to access the `FORM` scope. And the `FORM` scope will contain:

`form.tag = FT0077769,FT0077776,FT0077789`

If you've checked all three.

Does this help?

Comment: First, I don't see a cfoutput tag anywhere.  Next, you might want to mention what happens if no boxes are checked.